# Add noindex but follow on certain links

Tags: javascript

I have been searching online on how to deal with pagination duplication reported by search engines but i haven't found a solution. The only thing that helps is to use a robots.txt but i can't disallow every root paginated because of indexing.

My site has

```
example.com/page/1
example.com/category/page/1
example.com/author/page/1
```

I would like to place a wp function onto these pages, that will

````
noindex, follow
```.

If it's possible, then i will appreciate every effort!
````

Comment: Do it in the meta tag https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag

Comment: Hi Martheen, the WordPress structure has header.php page separately for pagination.php, and if i place that on header.php it would affect the whole site. Unless you have special way doing that?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-tag-manager/